# Presenting new AlertViewController after dismissing the previous AlertViewController - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to present new alert after user chooses the action in first alertViewController. Please find my code below.

```
@IBAction func forgotPassword(sender : AnyObject){

    //1. Create the alert controller.
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Forgot Password?", message: "We'll email a link to reset it.", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    //2. Add the text field. You can configure it however you need.
    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ (textField) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "Email Address"
    })

    //3. Grab the value from the text field, and print it when the user clicks OK.
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Send", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        let textField = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField
        let email = textField.text!
        FIRAuth.auth()?.sendPasswordResetWithEmail(email) { error in
            if error != nil {
                // An error happened.
            } else {
                print("error is nil")
                if self.presentedViewController != nil {
                    self.presentedViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
                    print("inside completion")
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Email Sent!", message: "Please check you email and follow the password reset instructions", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .Default, handler: nil)
                    alertController.addAction(action)
                    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)     
                   })
               }
         }
    }
}))
     // 4. Present the alert.
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Whatever code I have written in completion block its not getting executed so the second alert is not getting displayed. Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the UIAlertView will dismiss itself after its action.

```
//3. Grab the value from the text field, and print it when the user clicks OK.
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Send", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
    let textField = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField

    guard let email = textField.text else {
        return
    }

    FIRAuth.auth()?.sendPasswordResetWithEmail(email) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Email Sent!", message: "Please check you email and follow the password reset instructions", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(action)
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}))
```

Comment: I have tried this before, it works but will get lot of warnings like below.This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.

Comment: Do you have any other idea?

Answer (score -2):

Try this one inside the completion handler.

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

});

Comment: Inside the completion handler