# How to edit alertViewController without dismissing it accordingly to the action

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uialertview

I have an alert in my app where I put a textfield. The user can use it to add some values in an array. However I want all the values to be different. So if a user inserts an existing value, I want the textfield to be cleared and present a different placeholder text telling the user to insert a new value.

This is what I'm doing now:

```swift
func appendWord(){
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title:"insert a word", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alertController.addTextField { (textField : UITextField) -> Void in
            textField.placeholder = "insert here"
            textField.delegate = self
        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        }
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "save", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            let newName = alertController.textFields![0].text! as String
            //Useless Stuff to Append items here [...]
            
            //If the item already exists then i call the following function which is inside of an if statement...
            self.errorInCreation()
            
        }
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }

func errorInCreation(){
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title:"Insert a new word", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alertController.addTextField { (textField : UITextField) -> Void in
            textField.placeholder = "The word already exists. Insert a new one"
            textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "The word already exists. Insert a new one",attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red])
            textField.delegate = self
        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        }
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "save", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            let newName = alertController.textFields![0].text! as String
            //Useless Stuff to Append items here [...]
            
            //If the item already exists then i call the following function which is inside of an if statement...
            self.errorInCreation()
        }
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

This should present a new alertViewController until the user inserts a new word. However this doesn't happen. When I press the save button, the alert closes.

I tried to edit the current alert but it's not really possible.
How could I clear the inserted text, change the placeholder name and let the user insert a new word?

I found this person who has my same problem but the solution pointed out here didn't work.
[Presenting new AlertViewController after dismissing the previous AlertViewController - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38863720/presenting-new-alertviewcontroller-after-dismissing-the-previous-alertviewcontro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is actually quite simple: don't use UIAlertController. It's just a specialized presented view controller, and you don't get much control over how it looks or behaves; in particular, it dismisses when a button is tapped, which is not what you want. So just use a custom presented view controller where you have the kind of control you're after.